# Handling bad/malicious API requests in NodeJS/Express

Tags: json, node.js, security, express

I've created a basic api in node + express. I want to know how to handle bad JSON requests. I'm expecting JSON in my app. How do I check for incorrect requests, syntactically incorrect JSON or malicious things? I found if I sent syntactically incorrect JSON the node error would come out on the client side  of the api with the error details.

API example:

```
app.post("/api", function(req, res) {

    if(typeof req.body === "undefined") {
        badReponse("No body");
    } else if ( (typeof req.body.something === "undefined") ){
        badReponse("Request attribute missing");
    }

    function badReponse (msg) {
        res.status(500).json({error: msg});
    }

});
```

Comment: For request validation, you could use [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/). After defining the schema, use a middleware and check the incoming request with a validator like [tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4). You can also use the definitions with almost no further changes for documentation with swagger.

Comment: Thank you this is pretty much what I needed with the added bonus of working api documentation. Thank you.